# Extract only the last 7 days of data in Python

Tags: python, django

If I have such data and I want to extract only the last 7 days of data, how can I do that?

I tried to use Pandas examples, but I got errors such as `module 'pandas' has no attribute 'example'` or `'list' object has no attribute 'example'`, so I could not get the data for seven days.

Also, I'm using React for the frontend. When processing data like this, is it best to do it on the frontend side or the backend side?

```
"daily_report": [
    {
        "date": "2020/03/27",
        "count": 999
    },
    {
        "date": "2020/03/28",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2020/03/29",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2020/03/30",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2020/03/31",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2020/04/01",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2020/04/02",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2020/04/03",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2020/04/04",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2020/04/05",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2020/04/06",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2020/04/07",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2020/04/08",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2020/04/09",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2020/04/10",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2020/04/11",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2020/04/12",
        "count": 0
    },
    {
        "date": "2020/04/13",
        "count": 0
    },
]
```

```
    def get_daily_report(self, obj):
        data = Entry.objects.all().values(
            'created_at__year', 'created_at__month',
            'created_at__day').annotate(Sum('time')).order_by(
                'created_at__year', 'created_at__month', 'created_at__day')

        mappedData = {
            f"{record['created_at__year']}-{record['created_at__month']}-{record['created_at__day']}":
            record['time__sum']
            for record in data
        }

        s = pd.Series(mappedData)
        idx = pd.date_range(s.index.min(), s.index.max())
        s.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(s.index)
        s = s.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)

        now_ts = pd.to_datetime(s.index)
        now_ts = s.index.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')

        result = [{
            "date": f"{now_ts[i]}",
            "count": s[i]
        } for i in range(len(s))]

        return result
```

Comment: If you can, make sure your `date` dates are actual dates in your database. That will make things a lot easier. That means combining the year, month and day entries into one object.

Comment: You can use a filter in your Django query to immediately filter out objects beyond a certain date.

Comment: When you say "the last 7 days of data", do you mean with respect to the current day, or with respect to the most recent dates in your results?

Comment: This is from the current date and time to 7 days ago.

Comment: Please show the relevant `Entry` from your Django models file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter date like:

```
Entry.objects.filter(created_at__gte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=7))
```

Comment: Note that there is no indication that there is a `created_at` column. Just `created_year`, `created_month` and `created_day`. And these columns appear not to be date(time) columns, just (integer) values.